# How to match regex in crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I got a problem with crontab. I need to check the date to execute a script.

I want to run the command `[[ $(date '+%a') =~ Thu|jeu ]] && echo 'aaaaaaa'`. This wroks perfectly on the terminal. But if I put it in crontab : `[[ $(date '+\%a') =~ Thu|jeu ]] && echo 'aaaaaaa'` it didn't work.

In the `/var/log/syslog` I got  : `CRON[5461]: (root) CMD ([[ $(date '+%a') =~ Thu|jeu ]] && echo 'aaaaaaa' > /tmp/z.txt 2>&1)`

Did someone know why the command work on terminal but not on the cron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crontab default to `POSIX sh` and you're using a bash specific syntax.

The obvious solution is to set your shell in the crontab entry itself.
and cron also has a limited set of PATH.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

[[ $(/bin/date '+\%a') =~ Thu|jeu ]] && echo 'aaaaaaa'
```

Or just use POSIX sh syntax

```
case "$(/bin/date '+\%a')" in Thu|jeu) echo 'aaaaaaa';; esac
```

- Assuming `date` is really in `/bin/date` otherwise you will need to set the `PATH` as well in the `crontab` entry so you can just do `date` in the crontab.
- See `man 5 crontab`